# React-notify, toast show as normal text on top-left corner of website

Tags: reactjs, laravel, toast, inertiajs, react-toastify

I use react-toast, laravel, react and inertia. While i want run toast(message); toast show as text on top-left corner in broweser window

I try use standard layouts and basic toast codes.  I tryied using old code, diffrent views and configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot add css file to my `import` then you can properly implement `react-toastify`

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";

import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
```